How to put the system into a software-only freeze state?
On my system, s3 sleep is not supported. s2idle is advertised to be supported but doesn't work reliably. Hibernate works, but it is too slow to use for short breaks. (I am trying to fix the s2idle since many days, but that's a separate topic.)
Meanwhile, is there a way to do a "software-only" suspend? That is, suspend all user-processes, but keep all devices in their active state. This might not be very energy efficient, but something is better than nothing. A bonus would be the ability to suspend a few selected devices, such as network cards and turn off display backlight, for better efficiency.
If a ready-made solution doesn't exist, is it possible to do something like this with a custom kernel module?

Starting point is what Ubuntu product and release you're actually using but hasn't specified. Ubuntu LTS releases for example have kernel stack choice, with the default set by your install media used, so you can switch kernel modules being used just by switching kernel stack; so have you explored that?  You may also find some of the OEM modules do what exactly what you want; but the install media used will dictate if they were considered at install time (you've given no clues as to product OR release). You highlight kernel in your question, but haven't said what you're using.

@guiverc My question was not specific to a particular Ubuntu or kernel release. I just want to know whether something like this is doable, with a custom script or self developed kernel module as a last resort. BTW, I am using Ubuntu 24.04 release, and kernel 6.8.0. (For context, I am a developer and have written device drivers a long time back, circa 1999)

Kernel modules can be specific to a kernel; though as Ubuntu LTS releases offer kernel stack choice; the same module may work in different Ubuntu releases.. but anything as close to the kernel risks not being generic   (FYI:  24.04 LTS currently uses 6.8 for GA & HWE kernel stacks; but HWE will move (in time) to 6.11 etc, you only provided release and not Ubuntu product details in comment; its still not in your question though)
